# SELECT TableName.Col1 VS SELECT Col1

Tags: mysql, select

This might be a weird question but didnt know how to research on it. When doing the following query:

```
  SELECT Foo.col1, Foo.col2, Foo.col3
  FROM Foo
  INNER JOIN Bar ON Foo.ID = Bar.BID
```

I tend to use `TableName.Column` instead of just `col1, col2, col3`

Is there any performance difference? Is it faster to specify Table name for each column?

My guess would be that yes it is faster since it would take some time to lookup the column name and and differentiate it.

If anyone knows a link where I could read up on this I would be grateful. I did not even know how to title this question better since not sure how to search on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: This should not matter. The time to look up the columns is such a miniscule fraction of the total processing time of a typical query, that this might be the wrong spot to look for additional performance.

Second: `Tablename.Colname` **is** faster than `Colname` only, as it eliminates the need to search the referenced tables (and table-like structures like views and subqueries) for a fitting column. Again: The difference is inside the statistical noise.

Third: Using `Tablename.Colname` **is** a good idea, but for other reasons: If you use `Colname` only, and one of the tables in your query gets a new column with the same name, you end up with the oh-so-well-known "ambiguous column name" error. Typical candidates for such a columns often are "comment", "lastchanged", and friends. If you qualify your col references, this maintainability problem simply disappears - your query will work as allways, ignoring the new fields.

Comment: thank you for explanation. even if its slight difference in performance i feel better since I do spend time to write table names (sometimes short names) instead of just column names.

Answer (score 4):

If it's faster, the difference is surely negligible, like a few microseconds per query. All the data about the tables mentioned in the query has to be loaded into memory, so it doesn't save any disk access. It's done during query parsing, not during data processing. Even if you run the query thousands of times, it might not make up for the time spent typing those extra characters, and certainly not the time we've spent discussing it. :)

But it makes the queries longer, so there's slightly more time spent in communications. If you're sending the query over a network, that will probably negate any time saved during parsing. You can reduce this by using short table aliases, though:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2
FROM ReallyLongTableName t
```

As a general rule, when worrying about database performance you only need to concern yourself with aspects whose time is dependent on the size number of rows in the tables. Anything that's the same regardless of the amount of data will fall into the noise, unless you're dealing with extremely tiny tables (in which case, why are you bothering with a database -- use a flat file).

Comment: thank you for your answer. makes sense. It was just bothering me not knowing it for sure :)

Comment: +1, I forgot this aspect. I do believe though, that as long as we don't bust a MTU boundary, this should be negligable, especially with all modern NICs using interrupt coallescing.

Comment: It's **all** negligible, we're just debating how negligible it is. :)